# How to install .jar files via crosh

Tags: minecraft, chromebook, crouton

How can I install a `.jar` file with crosh? I've already installed Linux, but I need to know how to carry files from the ChromeOS over to Linux.

I'm trying to do this to install a Minecraft mod. I'm using an Asus C200 Chromebook.

Answer (score 1):

I use a Chromebook as well. Getting the `.jar` files to the Linux environment is easy. Both the Linux environment and ChromeOS environment share the same downloads folder, so once you download it on the ChromeOS side, just navigate to your `~/Downloads/` folder on the Linux side and the `.jar` file will be there.

To install the mod, you will find `minecraft.jar` located in `~/.minecraft/bin/`. From Nautilus (or most other file browsers), press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to see hidden folders the navigate to `.minecraft`. If in the console, type, `ls -a ~/` and you will find the `.minecraft` directory. Navigate to the `bin` folder. After that, just place the modded jar file in the `versions` directory and you're good to go!